# BBB - Trouble getting second SPI chip select with device tree

Tags: c, spi, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I have trouble to get second chip select working on the Beaglebone Black.

I used the .dts given in /lib/firmware with my distribution (Angstrom, kernel 3.8.13) :

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 CircuitCo
 *
 * Virtual cape for SPI1 on connector pins P9.29 P9.31 P9.30 P9.28
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    /* identification */
    part-number = "BB-SPI1-01";
    version = "00A0";

    /* state the resources this cape uses */
    exclusive-use =
        /* the pin header uses */
        "P9.31",    /* spi1_sclk */
        "P9.29",    /* spi1_d0 */
        "P9.30",    /* spi1_d1 */
        "P9.28",    /* spi1_cs0 */
            "P9.42",    /* spi1_cs1 */
        /* the hardware ip uses */
        "spi1";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
            bb_spi1_pins: pinmux_bb_spi1_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x190 0x13  /* mcasp0_aclkx.spi1_sclk,  OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x194 0x33  /* mcasp0_fsx.spi1_d0,      INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x198 0x13  /* mcasp0_axr0.spi1_d1,     OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x19c 0x13  /* mcasp0_ahclkr.spi1_cs0,      OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x164 0x12  /* eCAP0_in_PWM0_out.spi1_cs1   OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi1>;   /* spi1 is numbered correctly */
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&bb_spi1_pins>;

            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

                    cs-gpios         = <&gpio4 17 0>, <&gpio1 7 0>;
            spi1_0{
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };


            spi1_1{
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I compiled it with dtc and activate it with uEnv.txt :

```
capemgr.enable_partno=BB-SPI1-01
```

(Both HDMI and HDMIN capes are disabled)

I have the twos SPI device shown in /dev/ :

```
/dev/spidev2.0  /dev/spidev2.1
```

and the pins are used by the spi interface as shown :

```
    root@beaglebone:~# cat $PINS | grep spi1
pin 89 (44e10964): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_bb_spi1_pins group pinmux_bb_spi1_pins
pin 100 (44e10990): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_bb_spi1_pins group pinmux_bb_spi1_pins
pin 101 (44e10994): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_bb_spi1_pins group pinmux_bb_spi1_pins
pin 102 (44e10998): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_bb_spi1_pins group pinmux_bb_spi1_pins
pin 103 (44e1099c): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_bb_spi1_pins group pinmux_bb_spi1_pins
```

And the mode is good :

```
pin 89 (44e10964) 00000012 pinctrl-single
pin 100 (44e10990) 00000013 pinctrl-single 
pin 101 (44e10994) 00000033 pinctrl-single 
pin 102 (44e10998) 00000013 pinctrl-single 
pin 103 (44e1099c) 00000013 pinctrl-single
```

I successfully use a programm in C which use the first spidev (spidev2.0) with the first chip select, but the there are nothing on pin 42 when I use spidev2.1 (MOSI,MISO and CLK are working though).

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does `cs-gpios = <&gpio4 17 0>, <&gpio1 7 0>;` map to pins `P9.28` and `P9.42`?

Comment: it comes from the [P9 pinout table](http://www.elinux.org/images/5/5f/H9Pinout.PNG), it refers to the gpio number of the pin. Also, the gpio number should be gpio3 17 and gpio0 7, but according to http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-spi-1-0-and-1-1-with-device-tre-overlays-on-beaglebone/, in the device tree the number of gpio bank is incremented, so it becomes gpio4 17 and gpio1 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found out the answer myself :

The pin 42 is special since it's connected to two I/O. So in order to use one of the I/O, you have to put the other one as input.

source : Beaglebone black system reference manual http://www.digikey.com/web%20export/supplier%20content/ti_296/mkt/boards/BBB_SRM.pdf?redirected=1 page 71.

But now i have an other issue really strange... I posted it here : [Trouble with SPIDEV, device tree and .dtbo name with Beaglebone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138751/trouble-with-spidev-device-tree-and-dtbo-name-with-beaglebone-black)