# Trouble with SPIDEV, device tree and .dtbo name with Beaglebone Black

Tags: kernel, spi, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I have some weird issue with device tree. I found out that changing name of the .dtbo changed the beahvior of the kernel !

I have modified the BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dts given in /lib/firmware with Angstrom :

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 CircuitCo
 *
 * Virtual cape for SPI1 on connector pins P9.29 P9.31 P9.30 P9.28
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    /* identification */
    part-number = "BB-SPI1-01";
    version = "00A0";

    /* state the resources this cape uses */
    exclusive-use =
        /* the pin header uses */
        "P9.31",    /* spi1_sclk */
        "P9.29",    /* spi1_d0 */
        "P9.30",    /* spi1_d1 */
        "P9.28",    /* spi1_cs0 */
            "P9.42",    /* spi1_cs1 */
        /* the hardware ip uses */
        "spi1";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
            bb_spi1_pins: pinmux_bb_spi1_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x190 0x13  /* mcasp0_aclkx.spi1_sclk,  OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x194 0x33  /* mcasp0_fsx.spi1_d0,      INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x198 0x13  /* mcasp0_axr0.spi1_d1,     OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x19c 0x13  /* mcasp0_ahclkr.spi1_cs0,      OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                    0x164 0x12  /* eCAP0_in_PWM0_out.spi1_cs1   OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                    0x1A0 0x32  /* Other P42 pin, INPUT_PULLUP */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi1>;   /* spi1 is numbered correctly */
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&bb_spi1_pins>;

            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            spi1_0{
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };


            spi1_1{
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I compiled it to two names : BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo and BB-SPI1-01-00A0.dtbo

When I load one of them in /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots, the spidev behaves differently !

With BB-SPIDEV1, spidev1.0 works good without any issue. But the chip select of spidev1.1 doesn't work ! The pin 42 is in the wrong mode, and the pin is not allocated with spi1

On the other hand, with BB-SPI1-01 (this name isn't important, giving another name is the same, it just has to be different of BB-SPIDEV1), the pin 42 is well allocated :

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux# cat pinmux-pins | grep spi
pin 89 (44e10964): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
pin 100 (44e10990): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
pin 101 (44e10994): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
pin 102 (44e10998): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
pin 103 (44e1099c): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
pin 104 (44e109a0): 481a0000.spi (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinctrl_spi1_pins group pinctrl_spi1_pins
```

and in the good mode :

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux# cat pins | grep 964
pin 89 (44e10964) 00000012 pinctrl-single
```

BUT this time spidev1.0 doesn't work propely. The MISO line (so the input for the BBB), sees only 0, even if it's false (I checked with an oscilloscope).

So What could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dts looks almost identical to the original BB-SPIDEV1-00A0 source, except there is a line missing: `spi-cpha;` located in fragment 1, channel 0, under `spi-max-frequency`, and there are several differences in the muxing of your pins: SPI1_SCLK might be INPUT_PULLUP, also I don't see any relation between P9_42B (0x1A0) and the SPI Subsystems - you may be mixing it up with P9_42A (0x164) which has SPI1_SCLK (mode 4) and SPI1_CS1 (mode 2). Mode 2 of P9_42B is 'MCASPO_AXR2.'

Comment: I see P9_42B must be set as 'INPUT' so instead try mode 4 (which routes it to nothing): 0x34 ...or mode 7 which is gpio 0x37

Comment: none of the things worked... I tried mode 4, mode 7, setting SPI1_SCLK as INPUT_PULLUP, adding spi-cpha, same behavior. The second chip select isn't high at the boot anyway, on the contrary of the first one.

Comment: But thanks for the reply ! Anyway, it doesn't solve the different name issue

Comment: I believe I may know what the problem is: pins 100-103 and 89 are all muxed to the `multichannel audio serial port subsystem 0` [mcasp0] on startup as part of the BB-BONELT-HDMIN overlay. To remove the HDMI overlays, follow the instructions at the bottom of this page: http://tekuconcept.blogspot.com/2014/02/gpio-beaglebone-and-bash.html and then see what happens.

Comment: These are already disabled, i have this command in my uEnv.txt : `capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN`

And there are unloaded (I see that with `cat $SLOTS`).
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well, again i answer to my question myself. Actually, the Problem was : I was unable to use the Second chip select of SPI channel 1 (spidev.1.1). When I tried to do so, the problem of the names of dtbo appeared and i posted this question. However the name problem isn't resolved yet.

But the problem of

> BUT this time spidev1.0 doesn't work propely. The MISO line (so the input for the BBB), sees only 0, even if it's false (I checked with an oscilloscope).

has been solved by changing the mode of the Clock : 0x33 instead of 0x13. Although it's an output, putting as 0x33 change the pin to RXACTIVE_PULLUP. It must be enable that way to receive data.

The strange thing is that 0x13 worked perfectly with BB-SPIDEV1...

Thanks to TekuConcept for the help about the registers, if i have some extra times I will try to dig the registers.

Answer (score 1):

Set P9_42B to Mode 4 w/High Impedance (0x2C) - otherwise, the default is Mode 4 Fast-In Pull-Down. Unless this pin is modified by another overlay, no muxing is necessary for P9_42B.

SPI1 (as well as SPI0, I2C, & GPIO2) registers were giving me bus errors when I accessed their registers, rendering the device(s) disabled despite setting their status to 'okay' in respective overlay. So I checked the CM_PER register and sure enough: `IDLEST=3 [disabled]` and `MODULEMODE=0 [disabled]`. Though these tests were done on a Debian system, I'm pretty sure the same goes for Angstrom and all other distros.

To enable them, you will need to access the memory address(es) for Power and Clock Management through a preferred language of your choice:
**Via PRU Assembly:**

```
.origin 0
.entrypoint START

START:
    MOV  r0, 0x44E00050 // CM_PER_SPI1_CLKCTRL Register [reset = 30000h / disabled]
    LBBO r1, r0, 0, 4   // load register value
    CLR  r1.t16         // set IDLEST to FUNC
    CLR  r1.t17
    SET  r1.t1          // set MODULEMODE to ENABLE
    SBBO r1, r0, 0, 4   // store value
    HALT
```

**Via Python:**
 [Beaglebone IO using Python mmap](http://www.alexanderhiam.com/tutorials/beaglebone-io-using-python-mmap/)

**Via C/C++:** (similar to the python example above)
Referenced from: [vabi-robotics.blogspot.com](http://vabi-robotics.blogspot.com/2013/10/register-access-to-gpios-of-beaglebone.html)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define CM_PER 0x44E00000 //PG 157

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int fd = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    ulong* pinconf1 =  (ulong*) mmap(NULL, 0x0FFF, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, CM_PER);

    printf("INFO: %X\n", pinconf1[0x50/4]);
    pinconf1[0x50/4] = 0x00000002;
    printf("INFO: %X\n", pinconf1[0x50/4]); // conf. initialized

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** If this is not the issue and one channel *is* in fact functional, make sure that the channel is disabled before enabling the next channel. Also, confirm that the MS bit is cleared [*master*], PIN34 bit is cleared [*SPIEN is used as chip select*], and SINGLE bit is cleared [*more than one channel is used*] in the MCSPI_MODULCTRL register (SPI1: 0x481A0128)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i had to read about all the registers you were talking about. Well the register 0x44E00050 is 3000h (reset) when i read it, but when a read it DURING a transmission with spidev, it's 02h, so spidev must enable the register itslef when it needs it.

Comment: About the MCSPI_MODULCTRL register, i'm unable to read it without a transmission going on ("bus error"). When i read it, it's 1h, that means : "1h = Only one channel will be used in master mode. This bit must be
set in Force SPIEN mode.". In fact, i am using one channel, i just want to select the other Chip select (SPIEN in the doc). But I can't find the registers talking about the different Chip select (SPIEN) and their usages.

Comment: Compile the *.c file from the following link on the bone: https://github.com/TekuConcept/BBB_Backup/tree/master/workspace/BoneMemory , load the *.sh script into the terminal (> source script.sh), and then run the command: "> readm 0x44E00000 0" (read from CM_PER_L4LS_CLKSTCTRL register) and give me the hex value it returns. If the value looks something like 0x4102 then the cause is that the ICLK and FCLK are gated and the device is in IDLE mode. (The ICLK is what allows access to device registers)

Comment: As before, the value is different when my SPI program is running and when it's not. 0x4102 when not running, and 0x2004102 if it's running (meaning spidev is in use).

Comment: "> writem 0x44E00000 0 0; writem 0x44E00000 50 2;" Then you will be able to access the McSPI interface without it being 'in use' (no muxing required). 0x481A0000 12C & 140 [MCSPI_CHXCONF.FORCE/.EPOL] are the channel specific registers that control SPIEN. Also, a read from the register MCSPI_MODULCTRL yields 0x4 which means the device is in Master/ChipSelect mode but also in SYSTEST mode by default.