# Problem SPI DEV 0 multi Chip Select application in Beaglebone Black

Tags: c, spi, device-tree

I have a problem with SPI DEV 0 in BB multi Chip Select.
I use SPI0 with CS0 P9.17 for control a ADC. It work vary well.
I want 3 additional chip select pin using P9.15, P9.13 and P9.11. Another 3 ADC, one CS each. If P9.17 cannot be used at the same time as using gpios chip selects then I am looking to use P9.15/13/11 as chip select.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

I need to command four identical ADCs that I have on the board, all with SPI0 and each with its Chip Select.

Best regards

I see similar question in this link [Trouble with SPIDEV, device tree and .dtbo name with Beaglebone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138751/trouble-with-spidev-device-tree-and-dtbo-name-with-beaglebone-black/77693115#77693115)
I don't know the working way.

Comment: Which pins to use for your additional devices is not a software development problem that is on-topic. Vote to close.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only add some language tag if your question actually contains some code written in that language that is relevant for your problem. There doesn't seem to be any C code involved